# SymmetricDS Trigger-Based Update Cannot Routing

Tags: symmetricds

I have table `A` in `corp` and `store` node which has before update and insert triggers. The trigger just update other column in the current row that updated/inserted. And also I have been configured `sync_on_incoming_batch=1`.

But the problem is, when the row is inserted from `corp` then the column is updated by the trigger at `store`. The `sync_on_incoming_batch` is triggered, but it can't route to `corp` node.

I also have been set `ping_back_enabled=1`, and succeed to sync again to `corp` node but update loop is happened. How to handle this?

I think `sym_conflict` can handle this, but i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

the loop has to get broken. there's no other way around it. conflict detection wouldn't work because there's no change between destination and incoming data

Comment: 1k+ row of update loop, i think it's not efficient. What is the criteria of one row can be send back to last node?

Comment: how to change criteria of one row can be send back to last node? I want to change primary key based routing to all column based routing

Comment: because when routes back, the job only compare its PK, not a whole column

Comment: create another question and give it a context and a better explanation. it's hard understanding what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to allow changes from Store 1 to send up to Corp and then send back down to Store 2?   If so you will want two sets of triggers.  One set that is installed on corp with the "sync on incoming" flag checked.   The other set with the sync on incoming not checked and applied to the store.   This allows changes sent from corp to store to stop there and not loop.  Alternately it allows changes from store 1 to hit corp and sync back to all other store nodes except store 1.